# Div class="clone" in html

Tags: php, html, css, layout

I inspect the element of my website and I notice that the div of top-header have duplicate.

Why it is happened?

How to remove that clone and remain the original div top-header?

My [site](http://goo.gl/u7o6hS)

Here's the html:

```
 <div id="top-header" class="original" style="visibility: hidden;">

 <div id="top-header" class="cloned" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; z-index: 1; display: block; left: 0px; width: 1343px;">
```

PHP:

```
  <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
  <div id="top-header">
    <div class="ak-container">
        <div class="site-branding">

            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name') ?>">
            </a>
            <?php } ?>              
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <div class="right-header clearfix">
            <?php 
            do_action( 'accesspresslite_header_text' ); 
            ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php
            /** 
            * @hooked accesspresslite_social_cb - 10
            */
            if($accesspresslite_settings['show_social_header'] == 0){
            do_action( 'accesspresslite_social_links' ); 
            }

            if($accesspresslite_settings['show_search'] == 1){ ?>
            <div class="ak-search">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div><!-- .right-header -->

            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation <?php do_action( 'accesspresslite_menu_alignment' ); ?>">

            <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'accesspresslite' ); ?></h1>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
            'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

    </div><!-- .ak-container -->

 </div><!-- #top-header -->

  </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Comment: Based on the code you've posted, nothing in there looks like it could cause the duplicate. If it is, you should be able to narrow down what is causing it through selective commenting out of your php code.

Comment: Looking at your site, it looks like the php code is not responsible for the new element that's being added. If you look at the source (not the element inspector) you see that the second div is not there. This leads me to believe that this div is being generated by some javascript.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 - it's just a url with an ip address instead of a hostname - nothing special, but what does it have to do with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on JS files included in your site I may say that .cloned and .original classes are in 
jq-sticky-anything.min.js

It's a jquery plugin.

Moreover there is a var inside  element at the bottom of the page - and it's weird:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
```

`var sticky_anything_engage = {"element":"#masthead #top-header","topspace":"0","minscreenwidth":"0","maxscreenwidth":"999999","zindex":"1","debugmode":""};
/* ]]> */`

Maybe *someone* insert it for you.

Comment: I see. So that the plugin cause the cloning of top-header

Comment: I assume so. Pay attention to the last <a> tag - it has a bunch of JS includes inside, but useless itself - it doesn't have text.